# swift uiwebview inside uiscrollview contentSize expanded but not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have the following structure & constraints:

[image]

The `contentSize` of the `UIWebView` & `UIScrollView` is set correctly but the `UIScrollView` is not working properly.

After loading the HTML to `UIWebView` I'm setting the constant of the `NSLayoutConstraint`

What's the missing piece here? I have [a sample project created here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wejpsqam4606q1l/UIScrollViewBug.zip?dl=1)

A part of the code, check the [a sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wejpsqam4606q1l/UIScrollViewBug.zip?dl=1) if you need the entire project

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pageWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    self.pageWebView.scrollView.bounces = true
    self.pageWebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.pageWebView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true

    if let cBody = self.HTMLContent {
      self.pageWebView.loadHTMLString(cBody, baseURL: nil)
    }
    self.pageScrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
} 

internal func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    self.pageWebViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```